# Arduino read ISO/IEC 14443B through PN532

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, rfid, mifare

My task is to read `ISO14443B` through `PN532` with `Arduino`.

I found that `PN532` supports `14443B`, but its library does not.

Is there any method related to solve my problem?

Comment: Removed some text and improved readability

Comment: I have the exact same problem, searched for hours all over the internet and didn'f find anything nor anyone to help me atm.

Did you solve the problem?

I'll keep you updated if I find something.

Comment: nope.. i gave up.. i change my project then..